# Проблема с модулем argparse в python

Tags: python, парсер, argparse

Добавил дополнительный аргумент, и не могу ввести его ни с помощью `input()`, ни через командную строку. В случае с командной строкой вылезает ошибка, хотя ввожу, кажется, корректно. Дефолтного значения нет, поэтому, когда запускаю программу, вылезает ошибка

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My example explanation')
parser.add_argument(
    '--my_optional',
    type=int,
    default=2,
    help='provide an integer (default: 2)'
)
my_namespace = parser.parse_args()
print(my_namespace.my_optional)
```

Вот что получаю, когда ввожу с консоли:

```
python zadachki.py --my_optional=3  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python38\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource  
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)  
  File "C:\Python38\lib\codeop.py", line 178, in __call__  
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)  
  File "C:\Python38\lib\codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile  
    raise err1  
  File "C:\Python38\lib\codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile  
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)  
  File "C:\Python38\lib\codeop.py", line 143, in __call__  
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)  
  File "<input>", line 1  
    python zadachki.py --my_optional=3  
           ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Так вводить команды запуска нужно в системную консоль, а не в консоль интерпретатора питона

Comment: @andreymal Когда ввожу в системную консоль, выдаёт ошибку, мол, нет такого файла

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое, ввёл полный путь к файлу, заработало

Comment: Можно просто заранее перейти в правильный каталог (а если вы будете работать с относительными путями в скрипте, то нужно)